# Copy filtered JSON data from one file to another using gson library in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, filtering

I want to copy JSON fields from one file to another but only after the field satisfies a particular condition, as for example

```
{"dataset":
   [
      {"album_id":1,
       "album_type":"Live Performance",
       "artist_name":"John Doe",....
       }
   ] 
}
```

I want to copy only those records which have a user given artist_name or any other property, else skip the tuple for copying. I am using the following code to add the filtered records to a JSONObject "wr" which I then write to my output file. But its not giving me the desired results

```
public static void dumpJSONElement(JsonElement element) {
    if (element.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
        java.util.Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> entries = obj.entrySet();
        java.util.Iterator<java.util.Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> iter = entries.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            java.util.Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry = iter.next();
            if(entry.getKey().equals(filterKey)){
                if(! entry.getValue().toString().replace("\"", "").equals(filterValue)){
                    wr.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            else{
                wr.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            dumpJSONElement(entry.getValue());
        }

    } else if (element.isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray();
        java.util.Iterator<JsonElement> iter = array.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            JsonElement entry = iter.next();
            dumpJSONElement(entry); 
        }
    } else if (element.isJsonPrimitive()) {
        JsonPrimitive value = element.getAsJsonPrimitive();

    } else if (element.isJsonNull()) {

    } else {
        System.out.println("Error. Unknown type of element");
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple solution is create POJO which represent your json, than create a List using gson library.

and now by using a list you can easily filter.

Comment: Thanks for the option but the json files I want to handle are not pre-formatted. The user will be supplying the file so cannot get the json architecture in advance for POJO

Comment: still you can do, see answer.

Answer (score 2):

use code below code to convert your json string to generic java type  `List<Map<Object, Object>>`, use code below.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {

    String str = "[{'id':1,'name':'yogesh'},{'id':2,'name':'aarush', 'degree': 'MCA'}]";

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<Object, Object>>>() {
    }.getType();

    List<Map<Object, Object>> list = new Gson().fromJson(str, type);

    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));
    filterList(list, "name", "yogesh");
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(list));

}

public static void filterList(List<Map<Object, Object>> list, String key, Object value) {
    for (Map<Object, Object> map : list) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            if (map.get(key).equals(value)) {
                list.remove(map);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

here i filterd name=yogesh record.

**output:**

```
[{"id":1.0,"name":"yogesh"},{"id":2.0,"name":"aarush","degree":"MCA"}]
[{"id":2.0,"name":"aarush","degree":"MCA"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but its only holding good for single depth file, if I provide data like [{'id':1,'attributes':[{'name':'yogesh','age':32}],{'id':2,'attributes':[{'name':'aarush','age':20}], 'degree': 'MCA'}], then it fails to filter, is there any workaround to handle n-level depth in this?

Comment: why not, in same example use : String str1 = "[{'id':1,'attributes':[{'name':'yogesh','age':32}]},{'id':2,'attributes':[{'name':'aarush','age':20}], 'degree': 'MCA'}]"; in this case may your filter not works, but you have to change little in filterList method.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and I googled, read a lot about this. In conclusion, the best(most efficient) way (with gson) is to write a custom `TypeAdapter` for your case.

You can test sample code below (it is working as you expected):

```
public static void answer() {

    String jsonAsText = "{\"dataset\":[{\"album_id\":1,\"album_type\":\"Live Performance\",\"artist_name\":\"John Doe\"},{\"album_id\":2,\"album_type\":\"A Dummy Performance\"}]}";

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new AlbumInfoListTypeAdapter());

    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    List<AlbumInfo> dataSet = gson.fromJson(jsonAsText, List.class);

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(dataSet));
}

private static class AlbumInfo {
    int album_id;
    String album_type;
    String artist_name;
}

private static class AlbumInfoListTypeAdapter extends
        TypeAdapter<List<AlbumInfo>> {

    @Override
    public List<AlbumInfo> read(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {

        List<AlbumInfo> dataSet = new ArrayList<AlbumInfo>();

        in.beginObject();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            if ("dataset".equals(in.nextName())) {
                in.beginArray();
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    in.beginObject();
                    AlbumInfo albumInfo = new AlbumInfo();

                    while (in.hasNext()) {
                        String jsonTag = in.nextName();
                        if ("album_id".equals(jsonTag)) {
                            albumInfo.album_id = in.nextInt();
                        } else if ("album_type".equals(jsonTag)) {
                            albumInfo.album_type = in.nextString();
                        } else if ("artist_name".equals(jsonTag)) {
                            albumInfo.artist_name = in.nextString();
                        }
                    }
                    in.endObject();

                    if (albumInfo.artist_name != null && !"".equals(albumInfo.artist_name.trim())) {
                        dataSet.add(albumInfo);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Album info ignored because it has no artist_name value");
                    }
                }
                in.endArray();
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        return dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter out,
            List<AlbumInfo> dataSet) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();

        out.name("dataset").beginArray();
        for (final AlbumInfo albumInfo : dataSet) {
            out.beginObject();

            out.name("album_id").value(albumInfo.album_id);
            out.name("album_type").value(albumInfo.album_type);
            out.name("artist_name").value(albumInfo.artist_name);

            out.endObject();
        }
        out.endArray();

        out.endObject();
    }
}
```

You can modify the `read` and the `write` methods. Gson has many cool functions. I strongly suggest you to read samples at [this link](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/).

**Edit:**

Incoming json text:

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "album_id": 1,
      "album_type": "Live Performance",
      "artist_name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "album_id": 2,
      "album_type": "A Dummy Performance"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output at `System.out.println` at `answer` method:

```
[
  {
    "artist_name": "John Doe",
    "album_type": "Live Performance",
    "album_id": 1
  }
]
```